How can I share texture between contexts in webgl or webgl 2
I have 2 canvases and 2 webgl contexts created from these canvases. I have a texture cacher, I want to put the texture used on one canvas in the cacher and then if this texture is used on another canvas, I want to get this texture from the cache and use it instead of creating a new texture.
How can I share texture between contexts in webgl or webgl 2. I don't want the memory to get too high

It's not possible to share resources between contexts.
